# How to fix issue in AdMob implementation?

Tags: ios, admob

error message

> 2016-03-10 00:54:38.475 GoogleAdTest[2677:1499976] 
>       Google Mobile Ads SDK version: afma-sdk-i-v7.7.0
>
> 2016-03-10 00:54:38.475 GoogleAdTest[2677:1499976] 
>       -[UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbed26188a0
>
> 2016-03-10 00:54:38.480 GoogleAdTest[2677:1499976] 
>       *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbed26188a0'

code:

```
NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]);

// Replace this ad unit ID with your own ad unit ID.
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"myadmobcode";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[
                        @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a"  // Eric's iPod Touch
                        ];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: add -ObjC to Other Linker Flags

Comment: Already have it. Still get error :(

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it will solve your issue. Go to project settings > Build Settings And set -ObjC to Other Linker Flags.

[image]

Comment: The issue may be with ARC or something else. Give some issue.

Comment: Nope, that was a different build. Mine already has it but I still get the error.

Comment: Jozemite, you know that some problem can not be fixed without seeing any screenshot or projects settings.Its almost 6month, Still you did not any solution ?

Comment: My project already had the "-ObjC" on it. I installed Firebase and AdMob through Cocoapods. When I try to run the app, after going through all of Google's instructions, it gives me [UIView setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector send to instance, and it goes to the line where I have the adUnitID which is correct.

Comment: Figured it out. I forgot to set the UIView to the GADBannerView class...

Comment: please paste your changed line. I can not understand still what you changed.

Comment: I didn't change a line of code. I selected the UIView object in the Storyboard editor and assigned it to the GADBannerView class.